# How to drop a column using pyodbc

Tags: python, pyodbc

I am using pydobc to connect with my sql server. I have a table from which I need to delete a column.

I can read this table, the code I used to read this is as follows:

```
import pyodbc
cnxn = pyodbc.connect("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0}; Server=xyz; database=db; Trusted_Connection=yes;")
cursor = cnxn.cursor()

df = pd.read_sql("select * from [db].[username].[mytable]", cnxn)
df.shape
```

Above code works as expected. But when I try to drop a column from this table it says can not find the object.

Here is my code trial

```
query = 'ALTER TABLE [db].[username].[mytable] DROP COLUMN [TEMP CELCIUS]'
cursor.execute(query)
```

My question is how to drop this column. To add here this column has a white space in it's name.

Comment: Will you get the same error if you do a `select [TEMP CELCIUS] from [db].[username].[mytable]`? Also I strongly advise against whitespaced column names.

Answer (score 0):

Try: 
query = 'ALTER TABLE [db].[username].[mytable] DROP COLUMN "TEMP CELCIUS"'

OR:

query = 'ALTER TABLE [db].[username].[mytable] DROP COLUMN `TEMP CELCIUS`'